# modify small line in java script code

Tags: javascript, html

here is the code from the sender file , if i want to send the text field value (sms_name) from one html to another html , now how u can modify the code to send three test

```
value(sms_name,sms_number,sms_text);

html file code (sender):
      var sms_txt=get_the_value('messages');
      var sms_number=document.getElementById('recepient-number').value;
      var sms_name= document.getElementById('recepient-name').value;


// plz modify this line down to send more than one text field vlaue
      window.location.href = 'activity_log.html?sms_name=' + sms_name  ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
window.location.href = 'activity_log.html?sms_name=' + sms_name + '&sms_number=' + sms_number + '&sms_txt=' + sms_txt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this is you are looking for?

```
window.location.href = 'activity_log.html?sms_name=' + sms_name +'&sms_number'+sms_number+'&sms_txt'+sms_txt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Doing This:

window.location.href = 'activity_log.html?sms_name=' + sms_name+'&sms_txt='+sms_txt+'&sms_number='+sms_number';